# What substitutes xreadlines() in Python 3?

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.x, readlines

In Python 2, file objects had an xreadlines() method which returned an iterator that would read the file one line at a time. In Python 3, the xreadlines() method no longer exists, and realines() still returns a list (not an iterator). Does Python 3 has something similar to xreadlines()?

I know I can do

```
for line in f:
```

instead of

```
for line in f.xreadlines():
```

But I would also like to use xreadlines() without a for loop:

```
print(f.xreadlines()[7]) #read lines 0 to 7 and prints line 7
```

Comment: You *cannot* index an iterator. `zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6])[0]` -> error.

Comment: @KennyTM Your'e right. I deleted the part of me saying "you can index an iterator". I thought I can index an iterator because I can do range(10)[7], but it doesn't mean I can index an iterator. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The file object itself is already an iterable.

```
>>> f = open('1.txt')
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='1.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> next(f)
'1,B,-0.0522642316338,0.997268450092\n'
>>> next(f)
'2,B,-0.081127897359,2.05114559572\n'
```

---

[Use `itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html) to get an arbitrary element from an iterable.

```
>>> f.seek(0)
0
>>> next(islice(f, 7, None))
'8,A,-0.0518101108474,12.094341554\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

how about this (generator expression):

```
>>> f = open("r2h_jvs")
>>> h = (x for x in f)
>>> type(h)
<type 'generator'>`
```