# Read a text file into an array

Tags: delphi

How would I go about reading a text file from a file on disk into an array in memory?

Also, I noticed using ReadLn only shows the first line (seems kind of obvious, since it is ReadLn, but how would I go about reading the whole text document?)

Comment: Edited because the use of "write" was confusing, when the user meant "read".

Comment: coder101; please note that the accepted answer is using something called a List, and that this is the Right way to go. But since you used the word "array" specifically please be aware that Arrays and Lists are different (but similar) things in Delphi.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193483/how-to-save-string-into-text-files-in-delphi (based on the accepted answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function ReadFile(const FileName: string): string;
var
  Strings: TStringList;    
begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    Result := Strings.Text;
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

That returns the file's contents in a string which can be indexed and so could be considered to be an array.

Or perhaps you want an array of strings rather than an array of characters, in which case it's easiest just to use the string list directly:

```
var
  Strings: TStringList;    
...
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    Strings.LoadFromFile(FileName);
    //can now access Strings[0], Strings[1], ..., Strings[Strings.Count-1]
  finally
    Strings.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: File is not really a good name, though, since that is a reserved word in Delphi. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Er thanks, and procedures don't have return values either!

Comment: @David: in the implementation section of a unit, they can, IIRC. <g>

Comment: @David: Can't check, but I have seen code where a method was declared like `function X(...): SomeType;` and in the implementation section it was declared `procedure X;` and it returned a value.

Comment: @Rudy D2010: [DCC Error]: E2037 Declaration of 'X' differs from previous declaration

Comment: That is why I wanted to check it. I have seen it in older versions.

Comment: While it is more idiomatic to read into a String List, than into an array, the OP used the word array, so I think it important to point out that RRUZ's answer is more "pedantically correct", for those who care about it, there is a distinction between an Array and a List.  But if it was me, I'd be doing it exactly as shown above by David.

Comment: @Warren What Delphi RTL/VCL and indeed .net framework refer to as a list is really an array, in CS terms. Lists are linked lists in CS terms.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Delphi  <strike>XE</strike> 2010 you can use the [`IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllLines`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllLines) function to read the content of text file in a single line of code.

```
class function ReadAllLines(const Path: string): TStringDynArray;
class function ReadAllLines(const Path: string;  const Encoding: TEncoding): TStringDynArray; overload; static;
```

Comment: This is present in D2010 too. Astoundingly, it loads the text into a string list but then populates the dynamic array in a loop with SetLength(Result, Length(Result+1))!

Comment: @David, sounds similar to how dynamic arrays are made in .Net. Make a List then convert to array! I wonder what's the advantage with that method...

Comment: @sam it's not advantageous here and has poor performance characteristics

Comment: @David: can't check that (no Delphi here), but that sounds terrible. I'd guess one SetLength(StringList.Count) would do. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Why would you need to check it? Do you think I can't read Delphi source code?! Yes, one `SetLength(StringList.Count)` would suffice. That entire unit is littered with the Length := Length + 1 anti-pattern. I guess what could be checked is if the code has improved since my D2010.

Comment: @David: I meant check if this is still so in XE and XE2. And I always like to see such things myself.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah, I was just stunned to discover that suboptimal code myself right now.

Comment: @John As well as the lame perf, the function fails to return `TArray<string>` making it hard to compose with other code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, there was that issue as well. I guess it's an "opportunity" :)