# Why does the way of saving a string to a file affect results

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, localization

I have ancountered a problem in saving of a string containing German letters to a txt file.
The MCVE looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string; //alias for UnicodeString 
  tf: textfile;
  ms: tmemorystream;
begin
  s := 'ßüÜöÖäÄФфшШ';
  assignfile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt');
  Rewrite(tf);
  write(tf, s);
  closefile(tf);
  ms := tmemorystream.Create;
  try
    ms.WriteBuffer(Pointer(s)^, Length(s) * SizeOf(s[Low(s)]));
    ms.Position := 0;
    ms.SaveToFile('b:\tmp2.txt');
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If the string is saved directly to the file we get the following: `tmp.txt` – `?uUoOaAФфшШ`. The German letters are changed though Cyrrilic letters remain. If the string is saved by TMemoryStream the result is proper: `tmp2.txt` – `ßüÜöÖäÄФфшШ`. What is the reason for this?

**Appended**

I decided to add the HEX values for the given string saved in different ways:

For `Write` method:

```
data: array[0..10] of byte = (
    $3F, $75, $55, $6F, $4F, $61, $41, $D4, $F4, $F8, $D8
);
```

For `Write` method called after `AssignFile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt',CP_UTF8);`:

```
data: array[0..21] of byte = (
    $C3, $9F, $C3, $BC, $C3, $9C, $C3, $B6, $C3, $96, $C3, $A4, $C3, $84, $D0, $A4, 
    $D1, $84, $D1, $88, $D0, $A8
);
```

For `TMemoryStream`:

```
data: array[0..21] of byte = (
    $DF, $00, $FC, $00, $DC, $00, $F6, $00, $D6, $00, $E4, $00, $C4, $00, $24, $04, 
    $44, $04, $48, $04, $28, $04
);
```

For `TStringList`:

```
data: array[0..27] of byte = (
        $FF, $FE, $DF, $00, $FC, $00, $DC, $00, $F6, $00, $D6, $00, $E4, $00, $C4, $00, 
        $24, $04, $44, $04, $48, $04, $28, $04, $0D, $00, $0A, $00
    );
```

**Appended**

upon the valued advice of @Remy-Lebeau:
This method generates a file of 25 bytes long. It is alike with HEX generated by Write method called after `AssignFile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt',CP_UTF8);` with additional 3 bytes (BOM?).

```
data: array[0..24] of byte = (
    $EF, $BB, $BF, $C3, $9F, $C3, $BC, $C3, $9C, $C3, $B6, $C3, $96, $C3, $A4, $C3, 
    $84, $D0, $A4, $D1, $84, $D1, $88, $D0, $A8
);
```

Comment: See [unicode text file output differs between XE2 and Delphi 2009?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14243866/576719).

Comment: Thank you, @LU-RD. I have Delphi XE5. Your comment helped me. The code is working properly with the following line: `assignfile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt',CP_UTF8);` Please, post an answer, so that I could accept it.

Comment: I guess what you need to decide is how you wish to encode your text. You should take that decision actively.

Comment: Thank you, @DavidHeffernan. Did I understand you properly that writing of a string variable to a file requires explict indication of the encoding? But does that mean that writng a `File of somerecord` containing `records` with `strings` (of fixed length)  will lead to data corruption?

Comment: Simple question. What encoding do you want to use for your text.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have appended the question with HEX sequences for different ways of saving the. It might be interesting for the community. I think that I'll have to save in UTF-8.

Comment: Good to see you are no longer observing results using Notepad! I guess now you can see why you get an extra bytes with `TStringList` method.

Comment: Yes, BOM encoded as UTF-8 is exactly these 3 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, @FreeConsulting. It is. But what is the encoding then for TStringList by default?

Comment: Note that string of fixed length in Delphi is `ShortString` and it is single byte. Saving such `record` to file with UTF-8 encoding would require you use explicit `Utf8Encode` call.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, thank you for your time once again. I'll note your kind advice.

Comment: @asd-tm, there are pretty long chain of defaults and according to [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.Classes.TStrings.DefaultEncoding) Delphi on Windows will reduce your data to ANSI which doesn't suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To store unicode strings in text files with the Write/WriteLn procedures, you must assign a proper codepage first:

```
AssignFile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt',CP_UTF8);
```

To persist the file against different locales, you can put a BOM first in the file as well:

```
Write(tf, #$FEFF);  // An utf8 BOM
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that writing method of `TMemoryStream.SaveToFile` differ with that of `Write`?

Comment: Yes, the TMemoryStream stores the file in UTF-16 while this example stores the file in UTF-8.

Comment: That's rather bad advice. Since data unit of UTF-8 fits one byte, Byte Order Mark [is redundant with UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2223926/205376) encoding and it's use discouraged by Unicode Consortium.

Comment: @FreeConsulting, note that I used the word "can". There are circumstances where a BOM is a better choice for UTF-8 files.

Comment: @LURD, sure thing. But I do not agree on your rationale to use it. UTF-8 encoded files are already compatible with any locale, regardless of BOM presence. Requirement to include or exclude BOM is merely a matter of support for old and/or broken software implementations.

Answer (score 2):

I belibe allways use the function in the RTL if they can do the job. And in this case TStringList does the trick for you in a very simple way:

In this small example I save a stringlist to a text file and loads it back again. Just to prove it works I've added an Assert test after Iøve loaded the text file again.

So no need to use `MemoryStream` and concerning about `BOM`. Use a TStringList, because it have all the functionality you need.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: String;
begin
  s := 'ßüÜöÖäÄФфшШ';

  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      Text := s;
      SaveToFile('C:\aa\tmp3.txt', TEncoding.Unicode);
    finally
      free;
    end;

  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      LoadFromFile('C:\aa\tmp3.txt');
      Assert(Strings[0] = s, '');
    finally
      free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: It's really necessary to mention what your example writes UTF-16 LE (and reads unspecified) encoding.

Comment: Thank you, @JensBorrisholt. Sorry, I can not accept more then one answer, I could only upvote. I've noticed that the size of the files differ. If it was written by `TMemoryStream` or by `Write` after calling `AssignFile(tf, 'b:\tmp.txt',CP_UTF8);` the size was 22 bytes. I thought that a 11 characters long string was to have 22 bytes size + BOM 2 bytes, wasn't it? After writing with TStringList it was 28 bytes. If I open these files with NotePad they present the same string. Does that mean, that if a file is written with `TStringList` it must be read by `TStringList` as well?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt, OK, not "unspecified", but rather "detected using `Preamble`". As you see, failing to **clearly indicate encoding** used, you caused more confusion to an OP.

Comment: @asd-tm it's ok. The reason for the extra bytes is that I saved it using Unicode and not UTF8. If you want it saved in UTF8 replace  TEncoding.Unicode with  TEncoding.UTF8

Comment: The reason why I do not specify encoding when loading is becauseTStringlist detects the encoding automatically

Comment: UPs didn't see your question. No you can write with TStringlist and read it with Tmemorystream

Comment: @asd-tm, UTF-8 BOM is 3 bytes, not 2.

Comment: @JensBorrisholt, I know the reason, but an OP and any further readers might not. Please clearly indicate what you were doing while writing the resulting file.

Comment: Sadly, I failed to convince you. Downvoted because of that and the possible bug with extra bytes.

Comment: @FreeConsulting first of all the answer about Unicode vs UTF8 wasn't for you som please be querit , and wait until you are asked. Second it wasnt a bug, it was just an other codepage.

Comment: You could post better quality answer for me to be satisfied. Meanwhile, 11 Unicode characters as per OP encoded using UTF-16LE + BOM preamble = 24 bytes, not 28.

Comment: As said before: Nobody called your number.

Comment: Dear Jens Borrisholt and @FreeConsulting. I have just appended my question by the HEXes for different ways of saving the string.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, try using a `TStreamWriter`, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: string; //alias for UnicodeString 
  writer: TStreamWriter;
begin
  s := 'ßüÜöÖäÄФфшШ';
  writer := TStreamWriter.Create('b:\tmp.txt', False, TEncoding.UTF8);
  try
    writer.Write(s);
  finally
    writer.Free;
  end;
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    writer := TStreamWriter.Create(ms, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      writer.Write(s);
    finally
      writer.Free;
    end;
    ms.Position := 0;
    ms.SaveToFile('b:\tmp2.txt');
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, Remy Lebeau. I have appended my post with HEX generated by your code. All the answers are very useful and unfortunately I can accept only one. I can only upvote your valued consideration.