# System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetParent odd behavior?

Tags: delphi

The result of `GetParent('c:\1\2\')` is `'c:\1\2'`.

And the result of `GetParent('c:\1\2')` is `'c:\1'`.

Is this the normal/expected behavior? If yes, what is the logic behind it?

Comment: What is your directory structure/what files?

Comment: Function accepts trailing backslash as correct input, but doesn't process it correctly. Seems it is bug.

Comment: As a workaround you can change that to `GetParent(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter('C:\1\2\'))`

Comment: `GetParent` is not very smart - it doesn't actually query the filesystem to determine whether `2` is a file or a directory, nor whether the filename in the path is empty; it just removes everything from the end to the last instance of a backslash.

Comment: @J... It's useful to have functions that work on strings irrespective of file system

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It wasn't a criticism, and I agree - I use this function all the time and appreciate that it is lightweight and predictable in behaviour.

Comment: I agree with David. The function FAILS if the folder does not exist!!! How odd is this?! So, before using GetParent make sure you first create the folder. That's why I have a replacement that works with strings not file handles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour might seem a little odd but it is by design. This class is modelled on the .net class `Directory`. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) for `Directory.GetParent` says:

> The string returned by this method consists of all characters in the path up to, but not including, the last DirectorySeparatorChar or AltDirectorySeparatorChar. For example, passing the path "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\test.txt" to GetParent returns "C:\Directory\SubDirectory". Passing "C:\Directory\SubDirectory" returns "C:\Directory". However, passing "C:\Directory\SubDirectory\" returns "C:\Directory\SubDirectory", because the ending directory separator is after "SubDirectory".

Comment: Thanks for the link. Delphi's documentation does not mention the separator (backslash) 'problem'.